# Asterisk call transfer to queue

Tags: asterisk

I have two sip extensions: 200 and 300 and a queue, let's call it my_queue.
Extension 200 is talking to extension 300 and decides to transfer extension 300 to my_queue.
So extension 200 puts extension 300 on hold and dials the queue number in the dialplan that eventually will call

```
...
same => n,answer()
same => n,queue(my_queue,,,,${TIMEOUT},,,)
...
```

Now, at this point extension 200 is listening to the queue's MOH and 300 is listening to the call in progress (as expected).
When 200 hangs up (and uses the IP phone transfer), the extension 300 is indeed transferred to the queue, and if any extension in the queue answers, it is correctly connected to the extension 300.
The problem is that while extension 300 is waiting for some extension in the queue to pick up it is completely silent. It does not hear a call progress nor the queue's MOH.
Is there a way to make extension 300 hear the queue's MOH while it is waiting in the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try transfer to announcement, which after end go to queue. And hangup before announcemnt ends.

Or add ivr breakout menu to queue(will be silence till IVR, after that moh).